# Can I create a new AWS VPC with IP range 11.0.0.0/16 instead of 10.0.0.0/16?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-vpc

Can I create a new AWS VPC with IP range `11.0.0.0/16` or `173.0.0.0/16` instead of `10.0.0.0/16` or `172.0.0.0/16`?

The reason is I need to create a VPC-peering. If the new VPC IP range is `10.XXX` or `172.XXX`, it will conflict with IP range of existing on-premise or existing AWS VPCs. All the existing on-premise or existing AWS VPCs use `10.XXX` or `172.XXX`.

So I wonder if the new VPC I created can use `11.0.0.0/16` or `173.0.0.0/16`?

I asked because `11.0.0.0/16` or `173.0.0.0/16` look very strange. Usually `10.XXX` or `172.XXX` or `192.XXX` are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But you shouldn't.

From [RFC 1918 - Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918):

> **3. Private Address Space**
>
> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
> following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Basically, these blocks can be used to route traffic within a private ('enterprise') network and will never be routed across the Internet. These addresses have *not* been assigned to any specific Internet user.

Outside of these private address ranges, IP addresses have been assigned to specific users.

You can certainly use `11.0.0.0/16` or `173.0.0.0/16` in Amazon VPC and in your own organization, however **you will not be able to connect the network to the Internet** because somebody else has been assigned those addresses.

If your organization has totally allocated the `10.0.0.0/8` range, then it has probably been quite wasteful. A `/8` range contains over 16 million IP addresses. (See: [CIDR, Subnet Masks, and Usable IP Addresses Quick Reference Guide / Cheat Sheet](http://droptips.com/cidr-subnet-masks-and-usable-ip-addresses-quick-reference-guide-cheat-sheet))

You should have a chat with your network administrators to discover how you can recover some of the private address space.

Comment: Thanks John Rothenstein. Thanks for your answer.I understand now.  I found 192.168.0.0/16 is not used yet. so I decide to use it to create my new VPC. hopefully no issue.

Comment: I do not recommend that you use an entire `/16` block for your VPC. That would contain over 65,000 IP addresses, so you are likely to be wasting a large number of them. You should pick a smaller block (eg `/24` that contains ~250 addresses).

Comment: John Rotenstein: I got it. I will use a small block when I officially create the VPC.